# jquery click function inside a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, click

I have a foreach loop in php like below.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($query as $value) { ?>
    <button id="show[<?php echo $i;?>]" class="btn btn-success" type="button">View</button>
    <div id="blah[<?php echo $i;?>]">Joel</div>
<?php 
    $i++ 
 } ?>
```

Now this loop work fine and I am getting id for each buttons and divs with unique id. But I want to add a jquery click function like below.

```
$("#show").click(function(){
$("blah").hide();
});
```

But since it is inside a loop and have different id's with them how to add this jquery function for each buttons?

Comment: add attribute `onclick` to the html element

Comment: You can do it using `class` instrad of `id` and then using `this` on the jQuery code.

Comment: but remember the class is not used by other elements, otherwise it will call click on those also

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var n = id.replace("show",'');
 $("#blah"+n).hide();
});
```

Also replace your buttons with this code

```
<button id="show-<?php echo $i;?>" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Clear</button>
<div id="blah-<?php echo $i;?>">Joel</div>
```

Comment: this is a good idea also (no idid not downvote), i think the downvote came from the strings `[]`, just a little tweak and this should be ok too

Comment: this is the only answer i upvoted before adding my own, sorry kevin i'm just not a fan of making divs children of buttons ...

Comment: @ user3702775 : Your login is correct. But unfortunately it doesn't work in this condition. Can you please check

Comment: Is there any console error ? Also what do you mean by login ?

Comment: @Joel Says: Also the div with id blah is supposed to be inside button tag or outside button tag. You have not closed the button tag anywhere.

Comment: It is outside. I missed to add

Comment: Sorry. It was logic.. not login

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Small edits was needed. I removed [] and added your codes. Worked !!!

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

for php:

```
<?php foreach ($query as $key => $value) {?>
<button class="btn btn-success blah-toggler" type="button" data-target="blah-<?php echo $key ?>">
<div id="blah-<?php echo $key ?>">Joel</div>
<?php }?>
```

then in jquery:

```
$(".blah-toggler").on("click", function(){
    var t = $(this);
    $('#' + t.data('target')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

u should use following

PHP:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($query as $value) { ?>
    <button id="show[<?php echo $i;?>]" class="btn btn-success clickEvent" type="button">
    <div id="blah[<?php echo $i;?>]">Joel</div>
<?php 
    $i++ 
 } ?>
```

Here you are adding class="clickEvent" for the buttons . And At the end u will have jScript file with following content .which will take care what should happen , when the button with that class is clicked.

jQuery:

```
$(".clickEvent").click(function(){
$(this).next('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: is blah a tag for you or an id ?

Comment: @vortex , its sample , The main logic OP asked for is important. Can u check what op asked ? What should happen after clicking is depending on OP.

Comment: yeah i read the question. still looks better after editing :)

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : $("#AnyElementId").hide(); How can I give the div id since all div has different ids

Answer (score 2):

Use a class

```
<button id="show[<?php echo $i;?>]" class="btn btn-success mybutton" type="button">
```

Then

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    $("blah").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could also use a class. Then the usual:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($query as $value): ?>
    <button class="btn btn-success toggle" type="button">
        <div id="blah[<?php echo $i;?>]">Joel</div>
    </button> <!-- missed a closing button tag -->
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
        $(this).children('div').hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($query as $value) { ?>
<button id="show_<?php echo $i;?>" onclick=show(this.id) class="btn btn-success" type="button">
<div id="blah_<?php echo $i;?>">Joel</div>
<?php 
$i++ 
} ?>
```

javascript:

```
function show(id)
{
var arr = id.split('_');
$("#blah_"+arr[1]).hide("slow");
}
```

Comment: How to hide inside that javascript function?

Comment: Nice Work ... Perfectly for me